# Android 2.3 Unicode support

Tags: android, unicode, fonts, textview

I have an app, and i need to  display a lot of currency symbols. For this purpose i am using [font](http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html) (thanks to [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) library).

The problem: not all symbols are displayed!

Example: ₺ or \u20BA (Turkish Lira) does not show on `Android 2.3` but it is showing on `Android 4.4`

The thing is, that i use the same font on both devices. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Are you using the font through linking to the font file or referring to the font installed on the android device?

Comment: The font files are located in `assets` folder and are linked to the TextView. I can see, that the font is 100% used on the Androd 2.3 device, since the system just doesn't have it.

Comment: Could you post the relevant code required to show the font character so that we can help you out in resolving out the issue.

Comment: Well i've managed to fix it! I will post the answer right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after hours of struggling, I've managed to get it working!

It seems, that the internet has outdated versions of Roboto `ttf` files.

So fonts from these links don't work properly for some reason: [FontSquirl Roboto font](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto), [Material design Typography](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/typography.html) and etc.

TLDR:
I've managed to get a working font from android SDK (API level 21). On my system it's located here `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-21\data\fonts`. With these font files everything is working!